# How do I use the Azure WCF Relay and Hybrid Connections Buttons?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azureservicebus

I followed this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay)
which explains how to make a C# solution using the WCF Relay and everything works.

In the creation of the Relay namespace, however, I realized that there are two buttons:

**Add WCF Relay** and **Add Hybrid Connection** buttons

[image]

I wanted to know how and when to use, in the examples and in the Microsoft documentation there is no trace.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how and when to use, in the examples and in the Microsoft documentation there is no trace.

The [Create a hybrid on-premises/cloud application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay) tutorial you mentioned is creating the [Relay namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-create-namespace-portal) and create a NetTcp **WCF Relay** named products under the relay namespace. For **Hybrid Connection** under your relay namespace, you could follow [Get started with Relay Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-dotnet-get-started).

Additionally, you could also manually create the **Service Bus** and use `ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri` to create the WCF Relay url, more detailed tutorial you could follow [How to use Azure Relay WCF relays with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-wcf-dotnet-get-started).